# Free Code Camp challenge - Title Case A Sentence

Tags: javascript, title-case

I'm currently going through the First JS challenges of Free Code Camp.

I'm having trouble with the challenge titled Title Case a Sentence. In this challenge I need to write a function that capitalizes every first letter of a word in a given string, and lower-cases all the other letters.
[Here's](https://www.freecodecamp.org/challenges/title-case-a-sentence) a link to the challenge
I have written the following code, trying to accomplish the following:

SPLIT |str| TO AN ARRAY OF LETTERS

DEFINE LOCAL VARIABLE |toCAP| TO EVERY LETTER THAT COMES AFTER A SPACE |" "|

IF A LETTER COMES AFTER A SPACE

CAPITALIZE  |LETTER|

PUSH |LETTER| INSTEAD

ELSE

|LETTER| IS DEFINED AS THE LETTER

|LETTER| IS LOWERCASED

|LETTER| IS PUSHED TO THE LETTER INDEX

RETURN THE ARRAY WITHOUT SPACERS

```
function titleCase(str) {
  str.toLocaleLowerCase();
  var letterArray = str.split("");
  var letter = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < letterArray.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
        letter = letterArray[0];
        letter.toUpperCase();
        letterArray[0] = letter;
    } else if (letterArray[i - 1] == " ") {
        letter = letterArray[i];
        letter.toUpperCase();
        letterArray[i] = letter;
    }
  } 
  return letterArray.join("");
}

titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

Why isn't the second condition working, capitalizing the first letter of every word?

Comment: `toUpperCase()` doesn't modify the existing string, it returns a new string. Update `letter.toUpperCase()` to `letter = letter.toUpperCase()`.

Comment: If any of the answers helped you, please checkmark one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate approach using a forEach loop instead of the traditional for loop - first split the passed string into words, then split each word into letters. Capitalise the first letter and psuh all letters into an array that is returned.

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  var wordArray = str.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  var sentenceArray = [];

  wordArray.forEach(function(word) {
    var letters = word.split('');
    letters[0] = letters[0].toUpperCase();
    sentenceArray.push(letters.join(''))
  })
  return sentenceArray.join(" ");
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
console.log(titleCase("sHoRt AnD sToUt"));
console.log(titleCase("HERE IS MY HANDLE HERE IS MY SPOUT"));
```

Comment: Why not just `return wordArray.map(function (word) { ... return letters.join(''); }).join(" ");`? Also you forgot to change the rest of the letters to lowercase. You have to do that for the other test cases.

Comment: That wasn't a spread operator, that was just me omitting the rest of the implementation...

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the string to lowercase at first to account for all cases of input. I included some notes in the code. There was excessive string reassigning in your solution that I took out. Your second condition was not selecting the letters properly, you want arr[i] instead of arr[i - 1]

```
function titleCase(str) {
  var newStr = str.toLowerCase(); //hold a lowercase version of str
  var letterArray = newStr.split("");
  var letter = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < letterArray.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0) { //test for first letter
     letterArray[0] = letterArray[0].toUpperCase(); //reassign as the uppercase version
    } else if (letterArray[i] == " ") {
     letterArray[i + 1] = letterArray[i + 1].toUpperCase(); //if space is detected, set the next letter to uppercase
    }
  } 
  return letterArray.join(""); //join into a string
}
```

Here is the solution I came up with:

```
function titleCase(str) {
  var newStr = str.toLowerCase();
  var result;
  var arr = newStr.split("");
  arr[0] = arr[0].toUpperCase();

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i] === " "){
      arr[i + 1] = arr[i + 1].toUpperCase();
    }
  }

  result = arr.join("");

return result;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function titleCase(str) {
  return str.toLowerCase().split(' ').map((word) => (word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1))).join(' ');
}
```